# Remove Extra Columns In Pivot Table when Using Difference From

Tags: pivot-table

I have the following columns in my raw data table

```
     Category    Amount    Posted/Budget
```

I put the data into a pivot table and sorted to see what the posted amount and the budget amount was for each category. I created a second Amount field named Variance that uses 'difference from' and 'Budget' from *Value Field Settings -> Show Values As*  to figure out the difference.

How do I hide or get rid of the Budget column under the Variance section?

```
                 Amount                     Variance
            Posted     Budget        Posted      Budget
Category

Revenue      10,000    11,000          1,000

 COS         9,000     10,000          1,000

Pers Ex     -10,000   -9,000           1,000

 Op Ex       20,000    25,000          5,000
```

The solution I found, not elegant but works.
Recorded Macros to figure out the name of the range in the Pivot Tables I wanted to hide. Once I had the ranges figured out I ran the following Sub on the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

'Used to store selected Cell

Dim mysheet

Dim mycell

mysheet = ActiveSheet.Name

mycell = ActiveCell.Address


'Stops screen from flashing

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Select all cells

Cells.Select

'Unhide all cells

Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

' Select Variance and Posted data columns

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect _
        "Posted_Budget['Posted Data                        '] Variance", xlDataAndLabel _
        , True

'Hide selected Columns

 Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True


'Return to selected Cell

Sheets(mysheet).Range(mycell).Select

'Allow Screen to refresh

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```